# Sqlite Create temp trigger statement unsuccessful at query prepare

Tags: c++, sqlite

The following query gives `SQLITE_ERROR` at prepare function in sqlite:

Edit:

```
CREATE temp trigger TIME_INTERVALS_TRIG AFTER INSERT ON _TIME_INTERVALS WHEN  new.INTERVAL_START == 25;
```

This query works fine in sqlite command line, and can I please know the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: This does not work on the command line. Where is the trigger body?

Comment: Please see the edited query

Comment: This still does not work on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows, a trigger needs a body, i.e., something between the `BEGIN`/`END` keywords.

Your trigger must actually *do* something:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TRIGGER TIME_INTERVALS_TRIG
AFTER INSERT ON _TIME_INTERVALS
WHEN NEW.INTERVAL_START = 25
BEGIN
    SELECT 'do something';
END;
```